# C# - Runaway Button

Tags: c#, winforms

I need your help with the following program. I need to make a runaway button that should always be entirely contained in the form and should stay as close to the mouse pointer as possible without giving the possibility to be clicked.

My Program:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int i = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        successLabel.Visible = true;
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (successLabel.Visible == false) missedLabel.Visible = true;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        successLabel.Visible = missedLabel.Visible = false;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Minimum;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        if (progressBar1.Value == progressBar1.Maximum)
        {
            gameOverLabel.Visible = true;
            this.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            Form1_MouseClick(sender, e);
        }
        else
        {
            gameOverLabel.Visible = false;
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        gameOverLabel.Text = "Game over, you failed! " + Environment.NewLine + "Clicks: " + i.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        missedLabel.Visible = false;
        int x, y;
        Point formClientSize = new Point(ClientSize);

        Random rnd = new Random();
        do
        {
            x = rnd.Next(0, formClientSize.X - button1.Width);
        }
        while (x >= button1.Left - button1.Width && x <= button1.Right);
        do
        {
            y = rnd.Next(0, formClientSize.Y - button1.Height);
        }
        while (y >= button1.Top - button1.Height && y <= button1.Bottom);
        button1.Location = new Point(x, y);
    }
}
```

So, the problem is that in my program the location of button is generated randomly and that is not as close to the mouse pointer as possible.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a weird requirement. Are you making a joke app or something?

Comment: This is such a weird question, is this a homework task of a drunk teacher xD?

Comment: take a look at the Mouse Move event and move your button accordingly

Comment: So how do I move the button accordingly? xD

Comment: If you anchor onto the `MouseMove` you should be able to grab coordinates by simply doing: `e.X` and `e.Y`.  So you should be able to always change the button's position on the form according.

Comment: Expanding on @Greg's comment, you'll want to check the cursor's proximity to the form's borders (it's size, effectively) and move the button up / down / left / right so that it stays fully on the form. So if cursor.X < 100 (within 100 pixels of the "start" of the X axis) then you know to move the button to the right rather than the left.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but I still don't understand. In my code I should create a MouseMove event, get rid of Random(?) and replace ClientSize with e.X and e.Y? Or what should I do with e.X and e.Y?

Comment: @Quadrium https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code generates a random set of coordinates and continues doing so until those coordinates ensure that the new button location doesn't contain the current pointer location. But you don't want a random location; you want a location which is close to the current pointer.

Remove the random number generator all together. Instead, change your button1_MouseEnter method to move the button up the height of your button and to the left the width of your button. Do that until you hit an edge and then flip a bit and have it run down/right based on which window edge was hit.

That will get your button tracking with the mouse pointer. If you want it to track *closely* you'll need to add some logic that detects where on the button the mouse entered. If it entered from the top, move down a few pixels. If it entered from the left, move right. Etc. If you hit a window edge, add an additional direction to its movement.

Since this is a school assignment, I'll leave converting that logic into code as an exercise for the questioner.